# How can I import custom metrics from App Insights to Power BI?

Tags: dataset, field, powerbi, azure-application-insights

I'm able to add an App Insights DataSet through the Services part of "Content Pack Library".  The import of all of the data from App Insights APPEARS to work.  However, none of the custom metrics I've added to App Insights show up in the available "Fields" in the DataSet that was just imported.  All I see are pre-built fields for "sessions", "users", etc.  Is there a trick to getting my custom App Insights fields to show up in Power BI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PowerBI pack does not allow you much customization. However, you can use [Application Insights Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/) to build a custom query on your Application Insights data, then [export a PowerBI query](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-power-bi/) out of it that you can use to create a custom report.

As an alternative, you could use the continuous export feature to get the raw events collected by Application Insights, then import that into PowerBI and analyze the data in whatever way you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above comment.

Note you'll only have 7 days worth of data here.  For more data you would have to export to another storage account and query that account 
More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry